# How to keep dynamic item behavior after clicking any item in the list?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu like this. It can be view [ON MY WEBSITE](http://www.carantina.com) under **PRODUCTS** tab

Firstly, please hover on **PRODUCTS**.

If I hover on any items in the list, the content in the right pane changed dynamically. 
However, If I click one of them and try to hover on other items, the content in the right pane doesn't change automatically. I have to click others.

Basically, it loses it's dynamic behavior after clicking any items in the left item list.

I had written a jquery code for that but I think I am missing something.

```
$('.urun_tab').hover( function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('hoverblock'))
        return;
    else
        $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});


$('.urun_tab').find('a').click( function(){
    $(this).parent()
            .siblings().addClass('hoverblock');
});
```

This is the items part on my website

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs span4">
    <li class="active urun_tab"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Seksiyonel Kapılar<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a> </li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Otomatik Kapılar<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Kepenk ve Panjur Sistemleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#D" data-toggle="tab">Hangar Kapıları<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#E" data-toggle="tab">Otomasyon Ürünleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#F" data-toggle="tab">Yükleme Sistemleri<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
    <li class="urun_tab" ><a href="#G" data-toggle="tab">Yangın Kapıları<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-2x icon-white"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the class `hoverblock` to all the `li` elements when you click on a link. The hover handler is written to ignore `li.unrun_tab` elements that have the `hoverblock` class.

If you want the hover behavior to persist after you have clicked on an item in the product list, you have to either remove the code in your click handler that adds the `hoverblock` class, or remove the code in your hover handler that excludes class '.hoverblock` from hover processing.

It's a bit unclear what you want the behavior to be. What you are describing seems to be that you want a click on a product to do nothing with respect to the adjacent images.

Comment: Normally when you hover on the items on the left, the content on the right changes dynamically. However, if you click one of that items and if you hover on other items again it doesn't change dynamically. It loses its dynamic toggle behavior.

Comment: Right. You need to remove the `hoverblock` class addition, since your hover says `if($(this).hasClass('hoverblock')) return` ... meaning don't perform any hover action on anything with the class `hoverblock`

Comment: Rather than deleting the jquery code that you said, I deleted the other part of the code and it worked lol :) Anyway. I just have anoter question if you can help. If I hover on 'PRODUCTS' and hover on items that listed on left, the 'PRODUCTS' becomes like a class 'active'. I understand it by seeing a blue bar on the top of PRODUCTS tab. Do you have any ideas how to solve it? Normally ıt is supposed to be blue top border when there is an action in the dropdown. Not anytime.